# Is there a simple solution for $ \frac{d}{dy} \log\big( \int_{0}^{y} \exp(-a \frac{x^{3/2}}{y}+ b x)\, dx \big) $

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, exponential-function

What is the solution of
$$
\frac{d}{dy} \log\left( \int_0^y \exp\left(-a \frac{x^{3/2}}{y}+ b x\right)\, dx \right)
$$

Where a and b are constants. Even if the solution is an approximate solution.
The solution without log was explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530872/differential-of-definite-integral/1530875#1530875).

Comment: can't you just use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$?

Comment: yes, but I hope furher simplification be possible

Comment: No, no further simplification is possible. The methodology here is almost identical to your previous question.